# Positioning an Embedded Video in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently using a template for a website and decided to add a video to it - however, I am having great difficulty positioning it centrally to the left of the page. I have posted the code of the page below (it is a section of a one page scrolling website template).

```
<section id="one" class="main style2 right dark fullscreen">
<div class="content box style2">
                <header>
                    <h2>Latest News</h2>
                </header>
              <p>NASA's Jupiter orbiter, Juno, is now only 3 weeks away from its destination!</p>
            </div>        
  <div style="position: relative; top:1px; left:400px; width:200px; height:25px",></div>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t0Z5X6sQxeo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>      </iframe>
  </div>
    <a href="#two" class="button style2 down anchored">Next</a>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem seems to be the fact that your iframe is outside of your div. You have an empty div right before your iframe, which I assumed is where you want your video to be.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I fixed that, but now it's at the bottom of my page, how would I get it to go to the left and move up?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to go about is with a div wrapping the iframe refer to the sample code below.

```
<section id="one" class="main style2 right dark fullscreen">
  <div class="content box style2">
    <header>
      <h2>Latest News</h2>
    </header>
    <p>NASA's Jupiter orbiter, Juno, is now only 3 weeks away from its destination!</p>
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center;">
  <iframe width="560" height="315"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/t0Z5X6sQxeo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
  </iframe>
  </div>

  <a href="#two" class="button style2 down anchored">Next</a>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks for that! After style="text-align:center; what would the code be to move it left and vertically? I have tried various things but they don't seem to work.

Comment: You need to sort of plan the layout before you go about it. You can always use display:table-cell and then use vertical align.

Comment: <div style="text-align:center; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; left: 100px; top: 500px; "> Like this? It went to the left, but now I have no idea how to move it up.

Comment: Try to use margin-top and margin-left. or in this case even padding-top and padding-left also would help.

Comment: div style="text-align:center; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; margin-top; margin-left; padding-top; padding-left"> Like that? Sorry about asking so much, i'm relatively new to coding.

Comment: Just add the value style="text-align:center; padding-top:500px; padding-left;100px" change those values and you should be able to figure it out. Just upvote my answer if it was useful ;-)

Comment: Tried that out but now the video disappeared :? Where would I add in the value style=? <div style="text-align:center; display:table-cell; vertical-align: middle; padding-top:500px; padding-left:100px;"> and yes, i'll upvote your answer, haha

Comment: Just look online for how margins and padding work. 100px and 500px is what i meant. those are pixel values to tell how many pixels it should maintain.